# DataStax Cassandra C# driver: WHERE IN (?) query with collection parameter

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax, cql

I have following code C#:

```
IMapper mapper = new Mapper(session);

//...

var names = new [] {"n1", "n2", "n3"};
//Generation of question marks   
var inStr = string.Join(",", names.Select(n=>"?"));
var users = mapper.Fetch<User>($"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name IN ({inStr})", names);
```

This approach works.
But maybe someone knows a more elegant solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know a more elegant solution. I can imagine however, that the driver doesn't support this feature from scratch, because using the IN statement for large lists leads to serious performance problems, as described in the following article: https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Fundamentally change our queries is not possible for me. Long lists transform to batches by 100 entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide a dynamic list of values in a single parameter, use the IN operator followed by the question mark placeholder without parenthesis in the query.

For example:

```
var names = new [] {"n1", "n2", "n3"};
var users = mapper.Fetch<User>("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name IN ?", names);
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. But because of array covariance parameters are passed so: new object[] { names }